# Problems with falign* environment

Tags: align, amsmath

I'm trying to get the following to line up along the = but for some reason it's not working.

```
\begin{falign*}
\begin{split}

\int_{S_{min}}^{\infty} S \ S^{-\frac{5}{2}} \ dS 
  &= \int_{S_{min}}^{\infty} S^{-\frac{3}{2}} \ dS \\
  &\propto \bigg[S^{-\frac{1}{2}}\bigg]^{S_{min}}_{\infty} \\
  &\propto \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{S_{min}}}
  
\end{split}
\end{falign*}
```

When compiled I get:

[image]

If it is relevant I'm using overleaf. I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious so any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Where did you get this `falign*`  environment? I only know `flalign*`, or more simply, `align*`.

Comment: Where did you find `falign*`? It's not a standard environment. Anyway, the problem is quite likely in the blank lines. Remove them.

Comment: Isn't the environment callse `flalign*` instead of `falign*`? Also, make sure, you don't have any empty lines inside of math environments.

Comment: Huh now i'm not sure where falign* came from, I've just used it for ages and honestly can't remember where I got it from but it aligns everything left and removes the numbering. Switched to flalign* and removed the spaces, it's lined up but it's centered again which I don't want, so I've got to figure that out. Thanks folx.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you got `falign*` from, but it's not a standard environment. You possibly mean `flalign*`.

There must be no blank line inside math displays. And you don't want `split` inside, but at least a line with three alignment points, in order to achieve left alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Some text before the display
some text before the display
some text before the display
some text before the display
\begin{flalign*}
\int_{S_{\min}}^{\infty} S \, S^{-\frac{5}{2}} \, dS
  &= \int_{S_{\min}}^{\infty} S^{-\frac{3}{2}} \, dS \\
  &\propto \biggl[S^{-\frac{1}{2}}\biggr]^{S_{\min}}_{\infty} \\
  &\propto \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{S_{\min}}}
&&
\end{flalign*}
and some text after it.

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I see no reason for left alignment.

Note `\min` rather than `min`. It “should” be `\mathrm{min}`, but the final result is the same. Using `\,` is preferable to “backslash-space”; `\biggl` (left) and `\biggr` (right) should be used rather than the unadorned `\bigg`.

Answer (score 1):

If I've well understood what you want, it can be obtained with `align*` nested in a `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
\int_{S_{\min}}^{\infty} S \ S^{-\frac{5}{2}} \ dS
  &= \int_{S_{\min}}^{\infty} S^{-\frac{3}{2}} \ dS \\
  &\propto \bigg[S^{-\frac{1}{2}}\bigg]^{S_{\min}}_{\infty} \\
  &\propto \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{S_{\min}}}
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]